# Can SQL 2016 be used with Project 2016 for OLAP cubes?

Tags: project-server

The software reqs [document](https://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ee683978%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for Project Server 2016 clearly states that it supports "Microsoft SQL Server 2016 RTM". But further down in the same doc under the heading of "Cube Building Service requirements", it states: "SQL Server 2014 is the supported database server for SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise", and also: "SQL Server 2014 Analysis Services must also be installed on your SQL Server 2014 database server for your SharePoint Server 2016 Enterprise deployment if you plan to use the Cube Building Service in Project Server 2016."

So, is SQL 2014 Analysis Services required to support the project server cubes, or can SQL 2016 Analysis Services be used?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use SQL Server 2016 Analysis Services with Project Server 2016. The trick is to install **SQL Server 2014 Analysis Management Objects (AMO)** on each web front-end and application server in your SharePoint farm.

Download link for SQL AMO 2014: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=722556

See the detail requirements below:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj943761(v=office.16).aspx